# Display one of two messages (randomly, 50-50 chance)

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a .bat file that generates a Solar System and would like it to make planets in random orders. I was wondering if there was a code to make that possible. If not, any ideas I could use to substitute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a rand=%random% %% 2
```

`%%` is the "Modulo operator". (the rest, when dividing the first argument throught the second one e.g.:

5 modulo 2 = 2*2 rest **1** )

A modulo operator of `2` will give you `0` or `1`, an operator of `4` will give you `0`,`1`,`2` or `3`

Note for the passionate mathematicans: I know, for most operators, this is not *exactly* random, but for a game this effect is negligible (less than 0,0001)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the %random% variable.

Each time you read it, it returns a random number.

```
>echo %random%
11640
```

Comment: How this information may be used to "Display one of two messages (randomly, 50-50 chance)"?

Answer (score 0):

Your heading indicates you want more of a true or false scenario but your post indicates true random number, this will give you a 1 or a 0 randomly:

```
SET /a _rand=%RANDOM%*2/32768
ECHO Random true or false=%_rand%
```

This will give you a random number between 1 and whatever

```
SET /a _rand=%RANDOM%*372/32768+1
ECHO Random number between 1 and 372=%_rand%
```